# How to resolve $route in VueRouter without mounting <router-view />?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have a situation hard to handle, because of the way vue-router resolves itself.

So basically in an SPA:

1. I want to show a loader while fetching the current user's data & thus not render `<router-view />` until then

   - because the page rendered could need the user's data
2. The loader shown depends on a route parameter

Currently I'm doing something similar to:

```html
<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({ authReady: false }),
  created() {
    // just imagine this fetches the user and sets it on the global state
    this$store.dispatch('auth/fetch').finally(() => {
      this.authReady = true
    })
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <div v-if="authReady"> <router-view /> </div>
    <div v-else> <my-loader :type="$route.query.someParam" /> </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Full example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-route-loader-based-on-query-param-bfp0o?file=/src/App.vue
Try with url: https://bfp0o.csb.app/?type=something inside the codesandbox browser

The issue here is that `$route.query` & even `$route.params` only exists when the route is resolved, and that only happens if `<router-view />` is mounted.

How can I go around this?

Except by extracting  `<router-view />` outside the v-if & adding the v-if on all my route components :
which would be repetitive, cumbersome & prone to errors

My only solution today was to parse `window.location.search` myself to determine the query params.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I found a clean enough method for my use-case: wait for the router to be resolved with `router.onReady` hook.

It seems the router gets resolved in that hook, even when no `<router-view />` exists.

So the new code is:

```
<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({ routerReady: false, authReady: false }),
  created() {
    // just imagine this fetches the user and sets it on the global state
    this.$store.dispatch('auth/fetch').finally(() => {
      this.authReady = true
    })

    this.$router.onReady(() => {
      this.routerReady = true;
    });
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <div v-if="routerReady">
    <div v-if="authReady"> <router-view /> </div>
    <div v-else> <my-loader :type="$route.query.someParam" /> </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [nested route](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html) off the main route in `App.vue`, so that a `<router-view>` would be mounted (and `$route.query` would thus be available):

1. Copy your existing `App.vue` (which conditionally renders the `<router-view>`) into `Home.vue`.
2. Update your root route config to point to `Home.vue`; and to include a `children` array, containing the route config for the target page (`PageA`) with a blank `path`:

   ```js
   // main.js
   const router = new VueRouter({
     mode: "history",
     routes: [
       {
         name: "home",
         path: "/",
         component: () => import("./Home.vue"), // 1️⃣

         // 2️⃣
         children: [
           {
             name: "pageA",
             path: "",
             component: () => import("./PageA.vue")
           }
         ]
       }
     ]
   });
   ```
3. Update `App.vue` to show the `<router-view>`:

   ```html
   <template>
     <div id="app">
       <router-view />
     </div>
   </template>
   ```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-route-loader-based-on-query-param-3qsbd?file=/src/Home.vue)

Comment: well, it was well tried but doesn't work for me because it wait's for the inner router-view to be resolved which creates other issue in middlwares I would create.
Also creating a root Page for all my real pages feels not natural? What do you think?

It seems a good alternative though!